# reduciblility of linear combination of two polynomials in $\Bbb R[x,y]$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

For $f_1,f_2\in\Bbb R[x,y]$, let $S=\{k\in\Bbb R\mid kf_1+(1-k)f_2$ is not constant and reducible in $\Bbb R[x,y]\}$.

It is easy to see $\#S$ can be $0,1,2,3$:

$f_1=1,f_2=1$, then $S=\varnothing$, $\#S=0$.

$f_1=xy,f_2=1$, then $S=\{1\}$, $\#S=1$.

$f_1=x^2-1,f_2=y^2-1$, then $S=\{0,1\}$, $\#S=2$.

$f_1=x^2-y^2,f_2=y^2-1$, then $S=\{0,\frac12,1\}$, $\#S=3$.

Can $\#S$ be other finite number?

Comment: Clearly every k is possible. I think you missed some crucial assumptions one the two polynomials.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg we are considering the number of different k, not the value of k